# Debian/PipeWire disable bluetooth headset switching to HSP/HFP

Tags: debian, pipewire, wireplumber

Everytime I launch Audacity (which aggressively starts testing every possible input source), or even telegram-desktop, my headphones either switch to an HSP profile permanently (the A2DP options dispensary until I reconnect the headset), or they completely disconnect (probably because the headset cannot handle multiple profile changes within a second).

I have a dedicated USB Mic and do not need this useless feature with awful sound quality (even for voice calls). The only method I could find specifically for Debian was on [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/xocqxj/disable_hsphfp_in_pipewire_or_wireplumber/) but the instructions are incomplete (the guy references Arch Wiki which involves modifying a `.conf` file but uses `.lua` syntax). These files are in `/usr/share/wireplumber` in Debian, not `/etc/wireplumber`, but also the `media-session.d` subdir does not exist. It offers to "add a line" but I have no idea where I could add this line to not break the syntax in lua in a different file. I've tried both solutions by creating files under `.config/wireplumber` which is referenced as a possible local user config, but it changed nothing after restart.

How do I disable the HSP profiles entirely and only have A2DP profiles available. I'm running Debian stable with `bookworm-backports` enabled, and therefore on pipewire version `1.0.3-1~bpo12+1`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset#Disable_PipeWire_HSP/HFP_profile

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yep, thats one of the methods I tried to no avail (the options still exist, and it still auto-switches)